# How do you set the opacity of a Plotly Chart's bars individually?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, bar-chart, opacity

I'm working on bar chart using [plotly express](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/). I'd like to use discrete colours and set the opacity of each bar individually. At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(score=[93.3, 93.3, 92, 88], model=['model1', 'model2', 'model3', 'model4']))
fig = px.bar(df1, x='score', y='model', color='model',
             color_discrete_map={
                "model1": "gray",
                "model2": "rgb(255, 10, 10)",
                "model3": "rgb(255, 10, 10)",
                "model4": "rgb(255, 10, 10)"},
            opacity=[1, 1, 0.1, 0.1])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[80,100], xaxis_title='Score', yaxis_title='')
fig.show()
```

To generate the plot below:

[image: Visualisation of a Plotly plot without colour.]

I've tried adding separate opacities using a list of values, but that doesn't seem to work. Instead, plotly takes the first value in the list and applies it to all the bar charts.

How can I add opacity to each bar individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not verified that this technique works for all plotly, but you can set the alpha value in the format 'rgba(255,10,10,0.5)' in the color specification.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(score=[93.3, 93.3, 92, 88], model=['model1', 'model2', 'model3', 'model4']))
fig = px.bar(df1, x='score', y='model', color='model',
             color_discrete_map={
                "model1": "gray",
                "model2": "rgb(255, 10, 0)",
                "model3": "rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.5)",
                "model4": "rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.3)"},
            #opacity=[1, 1, 0.1, 0.1]
            )
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[80,100], xaxis_title='Score', yaxis_title='')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Tried that, didn't work unfortunately. Perhaps I have an older version, it's an airgapped machine. Thank you though!

Comment: My running environment is plotly 5.11.0. If you don't mind, I recommend you to use the latest version.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. However, if someone else confirms your answer with an upvote I'll accept it.

Comment: By the way, what version are you using?

Comment: 5.6.0 apparently, so not too far behind. Has there been a step change recently?

Comment: I ran my answer code in a Google Colab environment with plotly upgraded to 5.6.0. I share the [Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1znZfEBH8AULl8El4-67I7IIAOJisuFUx?usp=sharing). Is there any other factor other than plotly that is preventing the color from changing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251122/discussion-between-connor-and-r-beginners).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by digging deeper into plotly's [`Bar`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Bar.html) object.

Import `plotly.graph_objects` along with `plotly.express` with the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

With those imported you can create the chart object and then add the bars one by one to get the result you want:

```
# Create the initial bar chart
fig = px.bar()

# Add the bar chart for model 1, set its opacity to 0.3
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=[88], 
        y=['model1'],
        opacity=0.3,
        orientation='h',
        marker=dict(color='rgb(255, 10, 10)')
    )
)

# Add the bar chart for model 2, set its opacity to 0.65
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=[92], 
        y=['model2'],
        opacity=0.65,
        orientation='h',
        marker=dict(color='rgb(255, 10, 10)')
    )
)
fig.show()
```

This will give you something like the following:

[image]

As you can see, newly added bars automatically go to the top of the chart, so bare that in mind when you're setting up your own chart.